# Increasing WSO2 WSAS active for longer period

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Once I login to my wso2 WASA server. If I am not working frequently inside the

server, next time when I click any service or button it will again show the main login page.

How can I resolve this to keep the server active in the  web browser for longer period of

time without re login each time..

Can anyone help in this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase the management console session timeout in AS_HOME/lib/core/WEB-INF/web.xml

<session-config>

<session-timeout>15</session-timeout>

</session-config>

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the session timeout for your server instance